# Optimized way to solve this ArrayList problem

Tags: java, arraylist

list=[8,4,9,10,34,54,56];

1. Find min of list // `4`.
2. remove min and its adjacent elements from list // `[8,4,9]`.
3. Add min to integer variable sum. Repeat the steps again with remaining elements // `[10,34,54,56]`.
4. The output is single integer sum=68 (4 + 10 + 54). // `remaining element in list is [56]`

I tried in this way and this code keep running (does not print anything)
**Expected output: 68**

```
 List<Integer> ques=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8,4,9,10,34,54,56));
    int l=ques.size();
    int sum=0,min,index;
    while(l>=1){
      min=Collections.min(ques);
      sum+=min;
      index=ques.indexOf(min);
      
      if(index==0 && l>2){
        ques.remove(index);
        ques.remove(index+1);
        l-=2;
      }
      else if(index==0 && l==2){
        ques.remove(index);
        l--;
      }
      else if(index!=0 && l>2){
        ques.remove(index-1);
        ques.remove(index);
        ques.remove(index+1);
        l-=3;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: Just think, what happens if `l` value is `1`? Newbie tip: Try to debug your code adding breakpoints and going step by step.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JorgeFuentesGonzález  Debugged and got expected O/P

Comment: glad you sorted it out by debugging. Is a must skill when programming ^^

Comment: By the way: even your comments on the problem statement are wrong: When you remove the 54, you remove the 56 as well, so the remaining list is empty not [56].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the code is that the while loop condition is not being updated properly. It currently checks whether l is greater than or equal to 1, but it never changes the value of l inside the loop. Therefore, the loop runs indefinitely and never prints anything.

To fix the code, you can update l inside the loop based on the number of elements that are removed in each iteration. You can also simplify the if-else statements by using a single remove() call with the appropriate index.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ques = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8, 4, 9, 10, 34, 54, 56));
        int sum = 0;
        while (ques.size() > 1) {
            int min = Collections.min(ques);
            sum += min;
            int index = ques.indexOf(min);
            if (index == 0) {
                ques.remove(index);
                ques.remove(index);
            } else if (index == ques.size() - 1) {
                ques.remove(index);
                ques.remove(index - 1);
            } else {
                ques.remove(index - 1);
                ques.remove(index - 1);
                ques.remove(index - 1);
            }
        }
        if (ques.size() == 1) {
            sum += ques.get(0);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Output]

Comment: This is verty inefficient solution. You remove a random element from the `ArrayList`; it takes `O(n)` on each `remove()`.

Comment: You wrote in your answer: _it never changes the value of l inside the loop_ Actually it does. In each `if` condition the value of `l` is updated, namely `l-=2;` and `l--;` and `l-=3;` Did you miss those lines of code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

yes because you are not updating the value of `l` inside the while loop, which leads to an infinite loop, so you need to update the value of `l` inside each condition block where you remove elements from the `ques` list!

check this out:

```
List<Integer> ques = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8, 4, 9, 10, 34, 54, 56));
int l = ques.size();
int sum = 0;
int min, index;

while (l >= 1) {
  min = Collections.min(ques);
  sum += min;
  index = ques.indexOf(min);

  if (index == 0 && l > 2) {
    ques.remove(index);
    ques.remove(index + 1);
    l -= 2;
  } else if (index == 0 && l == 2) {
    ques.remove(index);
    l--;
  } else if (index != 0 && l > 2) {
    ques.remove(index - 1);
    ques.remove(index);
    ques.remove(index + 1);
    l -= 3;
  }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have four errors in your code. (Actually you have three distinct errors since you made the same error twice.)

1. After removing an element from a `List`, the list has one fewer elements and the index of each of the remaining elements is one less than what it was before the removal. Hence when you do: `ques.remove(index);`, the element that was at `index + 1` before the removal is now at `index`. You make this mistake twice.
2. When the `List` has only two elements, it doesn't matter whether the minimum element (i.e. `min`) is at index 0 (zero) or at index 1 (one). You need to remove it. (Try running the code when the `List` contains only 8 and 4.)
3. The `while` condition will **always** be true – since the `List` will never have all its elements removed. That is why *code keep running* – it is in an infinite loop. Hence the condition should be `l > 1`.

If you step through your code with a debugger and look at the contents of `ques` after each `remove` operation, you will see the first mistake in action.

Here is the corrected code:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Exercise {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ques = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(8, 4, 9, 10, 34, 54, 56));
        int l = ques.size();
        int sum = 0, min, index;
        while (l > 1) {
            min = Collections.min(ques);
            sum += min;
            index = ques.indexOf(min);
            if (index == 0 && l > 2) {
                ques.remove(index);
                ques.remove(index);
                l -= 2;
            }
            else if (l == 2) {
                ques.remove(index);
                l--;
            }
            else if (index != 0 && l > 2) {
                ques.remove(index - 1);
                ques.remove(index - 1);
                ques.remove(index - 1);
                l -= 3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you care about an optimization, do remember, that removing element from the `ArrayList` is ver inneficient. You should think about more suitable data structure like `Map`:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = { 8, 4, 9, 10, 34, 54, 56 };
    System.out.println(calcSum(arr));
}

public static int calcSum(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = createMap(arr);
    int sum = 0;

    while (!map.isEmpty()) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> min = map.entrySet().iterator().next();
        sum += min.getKey();
        int pos = min.getValue().iterator().next();

        removeElement(pos, arr[pos], map);

        if (pos > 0) removeElement(pos - 1, arr[pos - 1], map);
        if (pos < arr.length - 1) removeElement(pos + 1, arr[pos + 1], map);
    }

    return sum;
}

private static Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> createMap(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.computeIfAbsent(arr[i], key -> new TreeSet<>()).add(i);
    }

    return map;
}

private static void removeElement(int pos,
                                  int num,
                                  Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map) {
    Set<Integer> value = map.getOrDefault(num, Set.of());

    if (value.size() == 1)
        map.remove(num);
    else if (value.size() > 1)
        value.remove(pos);
}
```